# Generating line break in FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I have a text form, whose data is displayed in a PDF.

My problem is that when the value received by the PDF in variable exceeds 65 characters, instead of a line break, continue in the same line overlaying another element.

I have tried to apply the methods implode, wordwrap, but none has helped me to cut the string to reach 65 characters.

I tried to generate any condition to check if the length of the string exceeds 65 characters make a line break (`<br`>). But neither it has served me.

```
$pdf_observations = $_GET['pdf_observations'];

$pdf->SetXY(29.6, 85.6);
$pdf->Write(0, "{$pdf_observations}");
```

[image: Problem newLine]

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `MultiCell` method descrypted in documentation as

> This method allows printing text with line breaks. They can be
>   automatic (as soon as the text reaches the right border of the cell)
>   or explicit (via the \n character). As many cells as necessary are
>   output, one below the other.  Text can be aligned, centered or
>   justified. The cell block can be framed and the background painted.

This method can take some argument

```
MultiCell(float w, float h, string txt [, mixed border [, string align [, boolean fill]]])
```

More information you can find on the http://www.fpdf.org in manual section.

In your case you can use it with line

```
//example parameters - use anything that suit your things
$width = 100;
$lineHeight = 4;

$pdf->MultiCell($width, $lineHeight, "{$pdf_observations}");
```

In this example if your string can't fit to provided width then the rest of the string will be brake into new line when every line have provided height.