# Line break in FPDF PHP

Tags: php, fpdf

for example i have an address string like

```
John <br/> xxxxx <br/> AAAAA <br/> 104
```

I tried to display this address in pdf file using FPDF library,

```
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
$pdf->SetTextColor(32);
 $pdf->SetFillColor(255, 255, 255);
$pdf->MultiCell(0,5,nl2br($address),0,1,'L');
```

But its print same as in string, no line break is coming. is there any solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating line break in FPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38490454/generating-line-break-in-fpdf)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use \n as new line. And it should be quoted with " "

Comment: Can you tell me how can i use this, u mean instead of br?

Comment: Something like this:
$pdf->MultiCell(0,5," John \n xxxxx \n AAAAA \n 104"  ,0,1,'L');
Not currently able to test it.

Comment: @Jasiralwafaa - did you ever find a solution to this?